# subset a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
nested = {'a':{'aa':1, 'bb':2}, 'b':{'aa':3, 'bb':4}}
```

How to get the `result` as a subset of `nested` where the second key is 'aa':

```
result = {'a':{'aa':1}, 'b':{'aa':3}}
```

I tried this one but did not work:

```
result = {k1:{k2:nested[k1][k2]} for k1 in nested.keys() & k2 in ['aa']}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean a "subset by reference?"

Comment: It would be "better" if the result is just a reference to the original dictionary. so when I change result, the nested will be altered. I will edit it to take that word out.

Comment: So, you basically want a subset-*view* on the original `dict`. There is no such built-in functionality in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension with a filter for the inner dict, (this will create a new dictionary instead of modifying the original one):

```
{k1: {k2: v2 for k2, v2 in v1.items() if k2 == 'aa'} for k1, v1 in nested.items()}
# {'a': {'aa': 1}, 'b': {'aa': 3}}
```